# Как использовать loadCommand в CommunityToolkit.Mvvm 8.0

Tags: c#, winui3

По умолчанию в CommunityToolkit.Mvvm 8.0 добавилась асинхронная команда loadCommand, как ее использовать в MainViewModel при загрузки ?

```
namespace App1.ViewModels
{
    partial class MainViewModel
    {
        /// <summary>The backing field for <see cref="loadCommandCommand"/>.</summary>
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators.RelayCommandGenerator", "8.0.0.0")]
        private global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.AsyncRelayCommand? loadCommandCommand;
        /// <summary>Gets an <see cref="global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.IAsyncRelayCommand"/> instance wrapping <see cref="loadCommand"/>.</summary>
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators.RelayCommandGenerator", "8.0.0.0")]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
        public global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.IAsyncRelayCommand loadCommandCommand => loadCommandCommand ??= new global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.AsyncRelayCommand(new global::System.Func<global::System.Threading.Tasks.Task>(loadCommand));
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопрос вообще не понятен. Этот код вы писали, или взяли где? Похоже на то, что вы его забрали у сгенерированного кода...  Особенно `loadCommandCommand` радует). Вообще, использование команд через тулкит очень просты - берете метод (можно даже приватный), называете его просто, без всяких `Command`, например `private void Load(){ ... }`, дальше помечаете его атрибутом `[RelayCommand]`, все, за вас сделают все дела дальше, в XAML пишете `Command="{Binding LoadCommand}"` (внимание на то, что добавило `Command`), все, готово. Асинхронность аналогично, только `async Task` а не `void`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Просто обновился с CommunityToolkit.Mvvm 7.1 и там вот этот класс добавился сгенерированный. А у меня уже был метод такой и он начал ругаться на него. Вообще не понятно

Comment: Вы не должны вообще что-либо сгенерированное трогать, смотрите свой код, а не тот, что вам кто-то сделал автоматом. Как правильно использовать команды я вам сказал выше, сверяйте со своим кодом. Вот если что [документация](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/relaycommand).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Понял спасибо за ответ